# Google Map API 3: display marker within circle only?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is that possible to display markers within the circle only? Those outside of the circle will be hidden to user, while the circle move, the markers show and hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automagic "only draw things here" method in the API, but you can create a routine that uses the center of the circle (lat/long) and the radius to determine if the markers are within the circle and only display those.

Comment: how can i check if lat/lang in radius or not. I saw a function contansLocation() but do not figure how it works.